# Response of "Faulted" when sending a tweet using linqtotwitter

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I am trying to send a simple status update (tweet) using linq to twitter. I can connect ok but when I send a tweet I get a return status of "faulted" using the following code.

```
public async Task Tweet(string text)
{
    var auth = GetCredentials();
    await auth.AuthorizeAsync();

    var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);

    var tweet = ctx.TweetAsync(text);

    if (tweet != null)
        Console.WriteLine(tweet.Status);
}
```

My GetCredentials method is as follows:

```
private static SingleUserAuthorizer GetCredentials()
{
    return new SingleUserAuthorizer
    {
        CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore()
        {
            ConsumerKey = ####,
            ConsumerSecret = ####,
            AccessToken = ####,
            AccessTokenSecret = ####,
        }
    };
}
```

To confirm I have created an app in twitter. The credentials are correct (or at least copied and pasted from twitter) and I have full permissions to post messages to the account in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await *TweetAsync*, like this:

```
Status tweet = await ctx.TweetAsync(text);
```

That still isn't going to fix your problem all the way and here's why:

1. Since you weren't awaiting the async operation, you returned *Task*.
2. You didn't know this because *tweet* is *var*. I will update my demo code to use *Status* so people will see a compiler error if they use my example.
3. When you looked at *tweet*, you were viewing *Task.Status*, which was *TaskStatus.Faulted*.
4. *TaskStatus.Faulted* occurs because of an unhandled exception.
5. It's very likely that you received an unhandled exception because of an authentication error - 401 Unauthorized.
6. I wrote a FAQ with an extensive list of reasons why 401 exceptions occur and items to check for the reason(s): [LINQ to Twitter FAQ](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation).
7. You should wrap the code in a *try/catch* block, looking for a *TwitterQueryException* that will have more details, including the error text returned from the Twitter API.

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't an authorization (401) but your suggestions DID enable me to get to the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joe's Answer I was able to dig further into mine.

Using his suggested code and catching the exception I was able to grab this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0
```

I reran the nuget for Microsoft.Net.Http and the program sprang into life.

The library was installed BUT it was not added to the config file correctly.

Comment: That's Item #7 in the FAQ: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation